# Is Autosys same as CA workload automation tool?

Tags: autosys

I am trying to find if autosys and CA Workload automation tool are the same. Could not find much resources online. Wikipedia  mentions that autosys is the previous name before CA technologies acquired it. Can someone clarify.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CA_Workload_Automation_AE

Answer (score 0):

Yes autosys is Workload automation AE (AE stands for Autosys Edition)
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Broadcome acquired CA in 2018. The name of the tool technically did not change. It is CA Workload Automation AE (AutoSys Edition).